# Angular gives error "Unknown Provider", but works fine

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, angular-ui-router

Dear potential helper,

I'm working on a very simple Angular app.
I have a route, in which I want to resolve a "token" from a remote server. The retrieval works just fine, but for some reason I am unable to inject it into my controller.

Here is my route (Coffeescript):

```
module.exports = angular.module('app.register', [])
    .config(($stateProvider) ->
      $stateProvider.state 'register',
      url: ''
      templateUrl: 'app/register/layout.html'
      resolve: {
        token: ['tokenService', (tokenService) ->
          return tokenService.get()
        ]
      }
      controller: 'registerController'
  require('./registerController')
)
```

And here is my controller:

```
module.exports = angular.module('app.register')
  .controller('registerController', ['$scope', 'token', ($scope, token) ->
    console.log("Test")
    console.log(token.data)
  ])
```

When the controller is initialised, the correct token is logged in my console, but right afterwards the following error comes up:

```
Unknown provider: tokenProvider <- token
```

Can you help me resolve this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finnaly figured it out.

My controller was called twice: Once from my stateprovider and then again in my DOM with ng-controller="registerController".

Hope this helps someone in the future.